# Adding function to a piece of open source code

Tags: java, android, open-source

I am currently writing an Android app which used a piece of **open-source** code (it is a java class) on Github.

As development of the app go by, I now want to add some application-specified function to the class.
Not wanting to modify the original class (since it's open sourced), I thought of extending the class and modifying the extended one.
However, there are a bunch of **private** methods and variables in the original class, making inheritance do not work.

What is the recommended workaround for this situation?

Comment: Can you have some code examples ?

Comment: Depending on the license you do not have to make the source of the changes available. That been said.... Composition over inheritance, do you REALLY need to make changes to the existing class

Comment: It all depends on the license. If you can make it more flexible by adapting it for your needs it may be something others will find useful as well. Why wouldn't you want to contribute back to it?

Comment: In this situation I would wrap the class instead of extending it. (But you really should be careful with licensing issues.)

Comment: Which license is it under? If it's Apache your changes aren't required to be released, but integrating code from others may result in your entire project being open sourced.

Comment: @Jon You should read the tag wiki excerpt - [tag:licensing]: "This tag should be used for questions about software that *provides* licensing services, such as a licensing server or client. Don't use this tag to ask for legal advice about licensing."

Comment: @TobiasKienzler Thanks for the clarification, I missed that when I suggested it. In that case wouldn't this question be considered off-topic then, since the question isn't about implementing the license for the end user?

Comment: @Jon I guess it's ok - basically the question asks how to extend the functionality of externally provided classes, the licensing is merely motivation. There might be another question to dupe-close this one though

Comment: @Jon The license turned out the be Apache

Comment: If I modify the source file  directly (not wrapping or extending etc.) is it compulsory that I redistribute my modified version? From my understanding of the license, what I need to do is to retain the Apache license notice in both my derived source file and the "about" page in my final product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the class as part of your own API

If you really have to modify the source, you can always fork the project on github, and make your modifications to the source as you see fit. But I think this would be preferred:

```
public class OpenClassThatIsntMine {
  // Bunch of their code
}
class MyClass {
  private OpenClassThatIsntMine foobar;
  // My code, which "extends" the functionality of the open source class.
}
```